# Python: How to use methods from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am kind of a beginner in python and stuck with the part where I have to access methods from a class which reside in a different file.
Here, in File1 i am trying to access find_method from file2 to and do some operation and return values. But somehow its not accessing "find_method" from file2.

```
id_1.py (File1):
from base_file import base_file
class id_1:
  def condition():
     day_part_response = ...some response...
     current_time = ...some value...
     abc = basefile.find_method(x=day_part_response, y=current_time)

base_file.py (File2)
class basefile:
  def find_method(self, x, y):
     for day in day_response:
        start = day["start_time"]
        end = day["end_time"]

        if (condition):     -->(consider this condition is satisfied)
                
                self.start_time = start
                self.end_time = end
                day_id = day["_id"]
                self.entity_ID = day["entity_id"]
                self.restore = True
                self.create_entity()
                return self.start_time, self.end_time, day_id, self.day_part_entity_ID, self.restore
```

Comment: Are you sure you `import base_file` and not `import basefile`? Because this code should give you an import error, since the `base_file` module doesn't contain a member `base_file`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to import using `from base_file import basefile`. Make sure to use above import statement, your both files 1 & 2 are in same directory.

In base_file.py, check if for your given input satisfies the condition -

```py
if start < end and start < store_time < end or \
                    end < start and not (end < store_time < start):
```

otherwise it won't return any result and `None` will get returned as default.

In id_1.py, check if you are creating instance of the class `id_1` like -

```py
id_1_instance = id_1()
```

and then call the condition method on the instance

```py
id_1_instance.condition()
```

Since above call receives a returned value, make sure to print it so you can see the output.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing: from base_file import basefile
If 'base_file.py' is in the same directory as id_1.py
then the import will work. If you put the class in a
different directory, you need to add a line of code
before the import, something like:

sys.path.append("/home/username/python/classes")

You should also take a look at https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names
which gives you the recommended naming conventions such as:
methods should be in the 'snake' format: def my_method().

Class names should follow the 'camelcase'.
The class MyNewClass()  should be saved in a file named: myNewClass.py
So, you would do the import as: from myNewClass import MyNewClass.

I save all my classes in a single 'class' directory.
Of course if you are using Windows, you would have to specify
"C:\whatever".

Hope this helps!